# Android studio - problems with Layout

Tags: java

I have a problem - when I add any tool to my layout

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvPVB.jpg)

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: You are using a [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) which needs the UI elements' positions and sizes to be set by constraints. Apparently you didn't specify any constraints for this element.

Comment: Please add more context to your question, as of now it is unclear what you are asking. Show some effort, post what you have tried. Dont just expect people here to solve your problems without info to help out. Also, check the welcome tour and read How to Ask

Comment: Impreved spelling a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a different layout. Where you see the design tab at the bottom of the page just click text and then in the ConstraintLayout tag change it to RelativeLayout

should also automatically change the bottom tag as well.

Comment: the same problem when i change constrianlayout to relative layout >>> Look at the box below But I did not understand that I did not speak English You could simplify the problem for me,   https://i.stack.imgur.com/jleku.jpg

Answer (score 0):

[the same problem when i change constrianlayout to relative layout >>> Look at the box below But I did not understand that I did not speak English You could simplify the problem for me,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jleku.jpg)